# Beamer adding some text in subsection title page

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to add some text in the subsection page, using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Hello}
\date{2017}


\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}% sep= vertical space around text (between text and box border)
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vspace*{-1.pt}%    \vspace*{10pt}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsection title}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}

    \setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
    \setbeamerfont{subsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=blue!40}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=blue!20}

\section{AAA}
\frame{\sectionpage}


\subsection{01- xx }
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
xxxx\\

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some text to the `frame` that contains the `\subsectionpage` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Hello}
\date{2017}


\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
    \begingroup
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}% sep= vertical space around text (between text and box border)
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vspace*{-1.pt}%    \vspace*{10pt}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsection title}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \endgroup
}

    \setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
    \setbeamerfont{subsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=blue!40}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=blue!20}

\section{AAA}
\frame{\sectionpage}


\subsection{01- xx }
\begin{frame}
    \subsectionpage
    \begin{center}
        \textcolor{red}{Some comments to be added here}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
xxxx\\

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]